Can plumbing PTFE tape be used between PVC and metal?
A metal shower drain:

is screwed into a PVC drain pipe.
It was very difficult to remove: presumably because of the plumber's putty.   Is PTFE tape effective?  or will this cause problems.
The hope is that PTFE tape will make it easy enough to remove the metal show drain.

While using Teflon tape and/or paste (pipe dope) on the strainer threads isn't likely to cause any problems (and may make future removal/replacement easier), it isn't what I would do; I would use silicone grease (sometimes called "plumber's grease") on the threads. Either would strictly be for ease of future removal, not as any kind of "sealant".
Whatever you do with the strainer threads has nothing to do with (and does not replace) the plumber's putty, which serves an entirely different purpose. Putty goes under the lip/flange of the strainer to prevent water from leaking past/out from there.

The seal is between the underside of the drain flange and the tub. The threads on the drain flange are there to provide compression of the plumber's putty. you msut use plumber's putty between the flange and the tub. There is a rubber (or elastomer) washer on the underside of the tub between the flange on the lower drain pipe and the underside of the tub. This is not a seal but is there to prevent contact between the under flange and the tub. it cushions and distributes the clamping force. Some people find this in a parts package and think it goes on top between the top flange and the tub.

Maybe five years ago I repaced a lavatory drain in our house and the new drain DID come with a foam plastic ring intended to replace the plumber's putty layer between the drain flange and the wetted surface of the lavatory. The counter guy recommended against my using it and so I bought small tub of plumber's putty along with the drain At installation, however, I decided to use the foam ring rather than open up a cup of plumber's putty. It has not leaked so far.

I don't think that PTFE tape in lieu of putty will be a good substitution here.
PTFE tape is not a thread sealer; rather, it is a lubricant. It makes taper-threaded parts easier to turn so that they may be tightened enough that the tapered threads form a seal. It seems like the joint you're looking at here does not seal on the basis of a tapered thread -- if it were pipe of the same size, I'd be using a pipe wrench and putting 50-plus pound feet of torque onto it. Certainly this shower drain strainer is not torqued anything like that.
It's important to use a heavy-bodied sealant on these threads because the sealant, not interference between the threads, is what keeps the water inside. Consider what happens when hair or other matter builds up in the drain: the pipe backs up and the shower or tub fills with water; the seal on these threads must hold back that head pressure.
Based on the damage to the flange I wonder if you're not using the right tools or technique to remove the fitting. There are many styles of tub drain wrench which may make the job easier. (photo below: homedepot.com)


Better than tape I like to use PTFE Paste.
Doesn't get hard. Seals threads and actually makes them glide.  Use it on metal to PVC, CPVC brass, copper iron,stainless, almost anything.
